# How come JFrame window size in Java does not produce the size of window specified?

Tags: java, jframe, pixel

I am just messing around trying to make a game right now, but I have had this problem before too.  When I specify a specific window size (1024 x 768 for instance) the window produced is just a little larger than what I specified.  Very annoying.  Is there a reason for this?  How do I correct it so the window created is actually the size I want instead of being just a little bit bigger?  Up till now I have always just gone back and manually adjusted the size a few pixels at a time until I got the result I wanted, but that is getting old.  If there was even a formula I could use that would tell me how many pixels I needed to add/subtract from my my variable that would be excellent!

P.S. I don't know if my OS could be a factor in this, but I am using W7X64.

```
private int windowWidth = 1024;
private int windowHeight = 768;

public SomeWindow() {
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setSize(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.setLocation(0,0);
    this.setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I want the total frame that Windows
>   creates to be the exact size I specify

I don't understand your problem. Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that shows the problem.

If I run code like:

```
frame.setResizable(false);
frame.setSize(1024, 768);
frame.setVisible(true);
System.out.println(frame.getSize());
```

It displays java.awt.Dimension[width=1024,height=768], is that not what you expect?

> If there was even a formula I could
>   use that would tell me how many pixels
>   I needed to add/subtract from my my
>   variable that would be excellent!

Maybe you are referring to the space occupied by the title bar and borders?

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class FrameInfo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        Rectangle bounds = env.getMaximumWindowBounds();
        System.out.println("Screen Bounds: " + bounds );

        GraphicsDevice screen = env.getDefaultScreenDevice();
        GraphicsConfiguration config = screen.getDefaultConfiguration();
        System.out.println("Screen Size  : " + config.getBounds());

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame Info");
        System.out.println("Frame Insets : " + frame.getInsets() );

        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        System.out.println("Frame Insets : " + frame.getInsets() );
        frame.setVisible( true );

        System.out.println("Frame Size   : " + frame.getSize() );
        System.out.println("Frame Insets : " + frame.getInsets() );
        System.out.println("Content Size : " + frame.getContentPane().getSize() );
     }
}
```

Comment: I used this code and it tells me that the frame that W7 creates for is indeed the size I specified, but it is still a few pixels larger than my 1024 x 768 monitor.  I have 3 monitors (a 1920 x 1080 with a 1024 x 768 on both sides) and I noticed that even though I have specified setLocation(0,0) the window created in my main monitor is just a few pixels into the monitor to my left.  Annoying but I guess this is how W7 works.  I see no option except to deal with it or change the numbers in small increments until I get the desired results.  camickr for the win... (helping to right past wrongs).

Comment: Maybe you will find  frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); a better option? Then you don't have to worry about the manually specifying the sizes.

Comment: That also sounds like a good idea.  Is there anyway to use that while also specifying that I do not want the frame to go over a certain size?  For instance if I used that method on my set up the resulting window would fill up my main monitor at 1920 x 1080, I wouldn't want the window being created to ever be any bigger than 1280 x 1024  I'll read through the API and see what I can come up with.  Bare with me Camickr, there are going to be a lot more questions from me as I learn to code.  Please correct me if I use the wrong termonology too.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: frame.setMaximizedBounds(...);

Answer (score 1):

When you say the obtained window size is not the asked one, are you talking about the window, with its decorations ?

Indeed, window size is defined without OS specific window decoration.

Try to add

```
this.setUndecorated(true);
```

before the

```
this.setVisible(true);
```